# WWDC 2010 Session 401/402: Is the Quest application source available for download?

Tags: iphone

This is the "Game Design and Development for iPhone" talk.  I wasn't too clear on whether or not the Quest app they use throughout the presentation is downloadable anywhere for study.  If it is, where would I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not available for download - this was asked a while ago in the official Apple dev forums, and the reply from an Apple rep was along the lines of "no, and it will never be released".

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but there's your answer!

Comment: Here is the mentioned thread, have fun reading through the shitstorm (its actually pretty funny): https://devforums.apple.com/message/241130#241130

Comment: That's funny.  Throughout the talk they wave their hands and say "behold what you can do" and then...no code.

Comment: @Martin - I talked with them about it, and while the project was a great demo, it sounded like a lot of it was duct-taped together and wouldn't be what they'd want to have out there for people to learn from.  If they make an error in their released example code, it gets copied and pasted into thousands of projects by unknowing developers, so they get a little paranoid about this.